# Can not install openssh-server

Tags: server, ssh, tomcat

Sorry for dump question, but it's really hard to figure out what is wrong. 
I am trying to install openssh-server:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

I get very strange log, I don't know how is `tomcat` involved into this problem:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libntdb1 linux-headers-4.2.0-16 linux-headers-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-headers-4.2.0-34 linux-headers-4.2.0-34-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-35
  linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-36
  linux-headers-4.2.0-36-generic linux-headers-4.2.0-38
  linux-headers-4.2.0-38-generic linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic linux-image-4.2.0-35-generic
  linux-image-4.2.0-36-generic linux-image-4.2.0-38-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-16-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-35-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-38-generic python-ntdb
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up openssh-server (1:6.9p1-2ubuntu0.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K99tomcat' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'tomcat8' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rc.local if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop at service tomcat if started
insserv: There is a loop between service tomcat and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service tomcat at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service tomcat and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up thermald (1.4.3-5ubuntu3) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K99tomcat' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'tomcat8' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop at service rc.local if started
insserv: There is a loop between service rc.local and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting tomcat8 depends on rc.local and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service bluetooth at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop at service tomcat if started
insserv: There is a loop between service tomcat and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service checkroot at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service tomcat at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service tomcat and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package thermald (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 thermald
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could you, please, explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first sight, it looks like you have something that never fully installed.  Look at the line

```
2 not fully installed or removed.
```

While I'm not sure, you might have tried to install tomcat8 and it failed.  I'd start of getting rid of tomcat8 if you're sure you don't need it.

```
apt-get remove tomcat8
```

Also, let it clean up what it doesn't need any more.  That removes unneeded clutter in your output (all the linux- packages at the top).  It even tells you what to do for that.

```
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
```

When you're done with all that try installing openssh-server again and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I followed all you commands and every time I end up with `dpkg: error processing package thermald (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
 thermald
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Okay, the package thermald is not correctly installed.  Remove it too.

`apt-get remove thermald`

Comment: done, and while I am trying to install openssh-server I get `dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Okay, that's quite weird.  A package has pre-installation and post-installation scripts.  The pre-installation script is run before the files are copied, the post-installation script is run after the files are copied.
This says that the post-installation script has an error.  With a package like openssh-server that is really weird.

Comment: So...  Let's do the following.  Remove openssh-server, by purging it (remove only removes the binaries, purge also remove configuration files).  So start off with `apt-get purge openssh-server`.  Good, at this point, we are going to tell to the package manager to remove any superfluous packages it might have cached.  `apt-get clean` and for good measure `apt-get autoclean`.
Now try installing openssh-server again.

Comment: In some cases, this might be caused by a repository that's corrupted.  I had the case in the past, and switching repos fixed the issue.  We can try that afterwards in case the above doesn't work.

Comment: weird, but I can not purge: `dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1`

Comment: We're getting in a "pretty hardcore troubleshooting" situation.  At this point, I'd simply edit the post-installation script and set it to exit, but I don't know how familiar you are with editing scripts.

Obviously, I can't try on my machine what to do.  Try this (I'm really guessing, reading man pages, and Googling by now): `sudo dpkg --purge --force-all openssh-server `

Comment: Solved! Relevant issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/767008/loop-involving-service-apt-get-install-breaks-dpkg  I removed from `/etc/init.d` files `tomcat8` and `thermald`. Then purged  `openssh-server` and installed it again without issues

Comment: Glad you figured it out.